# Sublime Text remove python new property autocomplete

Tags: python, sublimetext

I love sublime text.  I know that I can disable autocomplete altogether in the settings, however I just want to disable one of the autocomplete options.

When you type an @property decorator in python you get an autocomplete option called New Property which if selected generates a getter and setter for you.  This ends up being more of a pain than a benefit for me.  Any ideas about how to remove that autocomplete option?

Answer (score 2):

## Sublime Text 2

You can remove `Packages/Python/New-Property.sublime-snippet`. The Packages directory location depends on the system you are using:

- Windows: `%APPDATA%\Sublime Text 2\Packages`
- Linux: `~/.config/sublime-text-2/Packages`
- OS X: `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 2/Packages`

## Sublime Text 3

The structure is a little different in Sublime Text 3. Personally I don't use it yet, but [this](http://maximilianhoffmann.com/posts/configuring-sublime-text-3) might give you some idea about how to achieve the same result in ST3.

By the way, these solutions are not ideal. When you reinstall or upgrade Sublime Text the snippet will be back. But I'm not aware of any way to disable snippet via user config.